# ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' --> tests/blacl.sol:5:13: | 5 | maapping(address=>boolean) isBlacklisted; |

Tags: solidity

i am developing a contract, everything works fine but don't know why i am having this error  `"ParserError: Expected identifier but got '(' --> tests/blacl.sol:5:13: | 5 | maapping(address=>boolean) isBlacklisted; | ^`

here is the code

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


//bep20 token 

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

   
    
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

   
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


interface IERC20Metadata is IERC20 {
   
    function name() external view returns (string memory);

    
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);

   
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
}


abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        this; 
        return msg.data;
    }
}

abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;
```

Comment: In line `maapping(address=>boolean) isBlacklisted;`, it should be `mapping(address => bool) isBlacklisted;`.

Comment: thank you....but now it says, identifier not found or unique

Comment: sir i cant thank you enough....is my contract fine now?

Comment: Change `address feeWallet = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000;` into `address feeWallet = address(0);` and then the contract will compile.